# How can I implement quotas in samba?

Tags: linux, windows-explorer, mount, samba, shared-folders

I want to create smb shares that are limited by a given quota size also I want to be able to modify the quota size in the future. While searching for a solution I came across the setquota command but I guess it only gives the option to implement per user and per group size quota limit but not on per folder/filesystem basis.

Then, I tried doing this using this https://superuser.com/a/976714 answer. The problem is file size modified using the "dd" command is correctly showing an increased size on the Ubuntu system, but the modified size is not reflected to the users (i.e. they still see the old size). The added space is shown as free space in parted tool.

Comment: If you are talking about a "disk image", you still need to resize the partition and the filesystem. (Neither of them is included in the answer.)

Comment: I see now I misunderstood. I suggest you use native quota to do quota. It is supported both by Linux and Samba. The specifics depend on the filesystem used.

Comment: After increasing size of image I see the extra added space is un-allocated (shown as free space in parted), I think it might be cause of problem so I am trying to find cli based method to merge this space in original partition. Am I in right direction?